# Create a flat Bucket structure in Sitecore 7

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

By default in Sitecore when we import Items in Bucket they are created in hierarchy by either the GUID or the Datetime of creation.
Is there a way to create a flat structure in the Bucket and have no hierarchy?
Would having a flat bucket structure affects the way Sitecore search for bucket works?

Comment: My concern with this would be that as the bucket grows, its performance would reduce. As far as I know, the primary reason for that default folder structure is to maintain performance at scale. Sitecore has always recommended a maximum of 100 child items under any node, but realistically it probably more like 30 - 40 if you care about speed.

Comment: I completely agree with @MartinDavies regarding his concerns about the performance.

Comment: Thank you for helping , my major concern was performance because we have approximately around 980 products. It looks like flat listing 1000 products under bucket would not be a good Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea of using the item buckets is to avoid having a large number of items physically stored under the same parent item. However, you can still have a flat list of items if you want by setting the BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath to blank or a given name. This key is located in the /App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Buckets.Config.

I copied here the comments written above the BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath settings:

> This setting determines the folder structure that is created in the
>   content tree. Edit this setting to change the folder structure.
>              The format currently supports date formatting, names, for example, "Content Bucket" or blank. Blank creates a dummy called
>   "Repository".